# Evaluation of a tough integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $D = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 < 1 \} $. Let $f(x,y) = \ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2} $. How can I evaluate this integral

$$ \int_D f(x,y) $$

??

Comment: A starting point: $\ln{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = \frac{1}{2}\ln{\left(x^2+y^2\right)}$

Comment: Try polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ln{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = \frac{1}{2}\ln{\left(x^2+y^2\right)}$

Converting to polar, the integral is:

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}r\ln{r^2}dr d\theta$

Which definitely looks easier.

Comment: How can limit of r be from 0 to 1 when the region of integration does not include the circle, but only inside of it. D:(x,y) s.t x^2 + y^2 < 1 not $\neq1$

Comment: Keeping in mind that this _is_ an improper integral...

Comment: Because the boundary has measure zero in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Integrating over the interval (0,1) is the same as integrating over the interval [0,1], because the inclusion of two points does not affect the value of the integral. (Unless we're dealing with some function that is infinite at a point).

Comment: And yes, as RecklessReckoner says, this is an improper integral, because $\ln{r^2} \rightarrow -\infty$ as $r\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Finite, nevertheless, but that will need to be shown.

Comment: Yeah I didn't work it all the way out because I figured from this point on it was pretty manageable.

Comment: i need some more clarification on the question i asked above in comment. can any1 plz explain?

Comment: @DavisYoshida That's all right, that isn't something _you_ need to do...

Comment: @ketan Sure thing. So, take for example, $\int_Dx\,dx$ where $D = \left\{x:0\leq x\leq 1\right\}$. This integral is clearly equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. If I said that $D = \left\{x:0 < x < 1\right\}$ this has no effect on the outcome, because the contribution of two points next to an infinite number of points is meaningless. That isn't a very rigorous sentence, so if you are interested in getting into the theory of this sort of thing, take a look at measure theory.

Comment: We wouldn't actually be integrating "down to zero" anyway, since $ \ r = 0 \ $ is not in the domain of the integrand.  One would have to write $ \ \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \int_t^1 \ r \ln r \ dr \ $ .

Comment: Yeah. I believe his question was more about the upper limit though, because the region was the open disk, not the closed disk.

Comment: I think this is an improper integral

Comment: @DavisYoshida   Right, for the reason you've given.  Sorry, I was still going on about the "impropriety" of this integral...  (There will be a brush with indeterminate products and L'Hopital.)

Comment: @MathcanbeFun It is. In order to fully work out the details you will need to do the computation: $\int_0^{2\pi}\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^1 f(r,\theta)\,dr\,d\theta$